# JQuery plugin for html 5 local storage?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Are there any good jquery plugins for using html 5 local storage?

Comment: I think your question could be easily answered with a quick google search.

Comment: I think this is a valid question, as it invites recommendations and a chance for people to supply their experience with various plugins.

Answer (score 16):

There's no need for plugins here, since you can access it very quickly:

```
localStorage.setItem("key", "value");
var value = localStorage.getItem("key");
```

That's not to say someone won't *make* plugins in the future (but how would you do cross-browser support? either there's local storage or there isn't).  But you don't need to wait on a plugin for anything here, you can start using it (provided the browser supports it) today.

Comment: Just check if localStorage is available.

Comment: I had assumed that a jquery plugin would support backward compatibility. No?

Does jquery automatically add that for older browsers without localStorage support?

Comment: A plugin would be useful to handle non-string data types, like objects.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a light plugin that has compatibilty with old browsers use this:

https://github.com/artberri/jquery-html5storage

Answer (score 1):

[jStorage](http://www.jstorage.info) is good. It makes use of HTML5 local storage if available — and it even works with IE6