# What would be alternative of window.sessionStorage in IE6

Tags: quirks-mode

I am having an application which has window.sessionStorage to store the persistent data but when we run this application in IE6 throwing an error saying that window.sessionStorage is null or not an object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [webshim polyfill localStorage undefined in IE6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074115/webshim-polyfill-localstorage-undefined-in-ie6)